# how to set amount in stripe php code

Tags: php

I am writing php code to charge credit card using stripe

Here is an example code:

```
<?
require_once('lib/Stripe.php');

Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_your_key_here");
if(isset($_POST)) {
$payment = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
'amount'        => '100',

'currency'      => 'usd',

'card'          => array(
'number'=> '4242424242424242',,
'exp_month' => '12',//,
'exp_year'=> '14',//,
'cvc'=> ''),//$_POST['cvc']),
'description'   => 'Test payment'
)); }

print_r($payment);
?>
```

This code will charge the customer for 100 cent!
Now what if i want to charge the customer with 10.99 dollar
I tried to change it to 10.99
I got this error:

```
'Stripe_InvalidRequestError' with message 'Invalid integer: 10.99' in
```

Comment: I think it's pretty clear, is `10.99` an integer? No it's not, you need to use only cents.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, sorry i am not english, i did't know what they means by "integer" i have read the documenation now, and i understand that the correct is 1099, only i have to remove the dot

Comment: Integer means whole numbers. `1,2,3,...10,11` are all integers. But numbers with decimal places such as: `10.99` are called floats.

Comment: What if I have an order amount as 10.995 usd how do I send it to stripe?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The stripe API [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#charges) states that accepts the amount as cents only.

`10.99` is a float value, not an integer. To get the amount, multiply the dollar figure by 100 to convert it to cents.

`10.99 * 100 = 1099 = amount`

Comment: Thankyou brendan, sorry i did not read the documenatation before, i used to use the dot with 2co and other merchants, now i understand i have to remove the dot, 10.99 = 1099

Comment: Solved and saved my day. Thank you. Is there any rational explanation of the why!

Comment: Bit of an old one but to answer your question @sdebarun it's actually because storing currency data in pence/cents is a far more reliable method as you're not going to hit rounding issues or situations with odd handing of decimals that we often see with databases and people incorrectly storing currencies as floats.

It feels very odd when you first see it but it does make things a heck of a lot easier to work with :)